# How to pass a variable to javascript from html as part of url

Tags: javascript, html

I have defined the following entry in my html:

```
script type="text/javascript" src="/dir/path/js/myApp.js?org=XYZ"></script>
```

Now i want to **read** the value "XYZ" as an **input** in **myApp.js**. How can i do this?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`split`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) or [`match`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp) or [some other `String` methods](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp) to extract the part you want to get.

Example below (you can run the code):

```js
// Assuming this is the url you get
var url = '/dir/path/js/myApp.js?org=XYZ';

// Split the url and get the second part
var query = url.split(/\?/)[1];

var value = query.split(/=/)[1];

console.log('Query: ' + query);
console.log('Intended value: ' + value);
```

In your example, you want to read from a `<script></script>` tag.

To do so, it is easier to first give the `<script>` an `id`:

```
<script id="example" src="/dir/path/js/myApp.js?org=XYZ"></script>
```

Then you get the `src` by:

```
document.getElementById('example').src
```

Then from here you can modify the code example above for your use.

**PS**

If you want to read from the URL instead, you can use `window.location.href` to read the URL as a string.

Comment: I wonder if the mention of window.location.href at the start of your answer will confuse some who read this. Anyway, I give you an upvote, as the solution in the second half of your answer is spot on :)

Comment: @athms you're right. I've restructured the paragraph order.